# Excel Macro search column D cell 1 copy paste column B cell 7

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Can someone help create an excel macro?

```
  A |  B |  C |  D |
----+----+----+----+
 20 |  ? | 75 |  2 |
 22 |  ? | 23 |  3 |
 23 |  ? | 25 |  5 |
 24 |  ? | 20 |  1 |
 50 |  ? | 36 |  2 |
 36 |  ? | 22 |  4 |
 75 |  ? | 12 |  1 |
```

If cell 1(75) from column C searches column A, if it finds 75(A7) then enter column D cell 1(2) into column B cell 7.
Repeat until column C is finished.
Please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any ideas, @AthomSfere

Comment: Another wording for the (confusing) question: If a value in column C exists in column A, write the value of column D (on column B) that is in the same row where that value is in column C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a macro at all.  Just use a function in column B.  Assuming you are on row 2 just enter this into B2.  Then drag the function down.

```
=IF(C2=A2,D2,"")
```

It's unclear if you mean that C searches ALL of column A, or just column A for that row.  If you want C to be looked up for all of column A:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2,A:A,1,FALSE)),"",D2)


RESULT:
    A   B   C   D
    20  2   75  2
    22  3   23  3
    23  5   25  5
    24      20  1
    50      36  2
    36  4   22  4
    75  1   12  1
```

If you mean that you want the value from D put into the same row where the match was found in row A, I'd actually just say flip the script to look for A in C then copy over D.  That will give the same result with less confusion.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE))

RESULT:
A   B   C   D
20  1   75  2
22  4   23  3
23  3   25  5
24      20  1
50      36  2
36  2   22  4
75  2   12  1
```

Comment: Had to change A3 to A1 to work. You are a Super Hero(user).Thanks,I hope you and yours have a Happy Holiday.

Comment: @Joe, you can click the check mark next to the answer to accept it.  You can also upvote it if helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Sub SRI()

lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 2

Do While (Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i,1) <> "")

strSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,1)

Set acell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C" & lr).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlVlaues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not acell Is Nothing Then

x = acell.Row

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4)

Else

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2) = "Not Found in Column C"

End if

i = i+1

Loop

End Sub

''***********COMMENTS*******************************

'Considered the first row  as some heading for each column.

'Taking the Column C valuesto "lr".

'Using a Do While loop for comparing the C column values with A column.

'The A column values are taken to "strsearch" one by one as the "i" value increases.

'Matching the "strSearch" value with C column values in "lr" and if the value matches that will be hold by "acell".

'Now using a IF NOT condition to pull the corresponding D column   values to B column.

'If  any of the A column values are not present in C column, then the corresponding B column is updated with a comment "not found in column C".

Comment: Could you please explain in some detail what you have done? Bits of code like yours are difficult to read, to understand, and then to modify, while a short verbal explanation might allow future readers to benefit from your answer, rather than trying blindly to replicate it.

Comment: Updated the answer with comments.

Comment: @SRI Could you also format the answer?  You have the ability to insert the code into a code block of you want